# Python Postgres JSON

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Currently as written I insert the payload as JSON into a single column. I want to break the k/v into columns in the predefined table.
The value from MQTT is always byte object. ie...

`b'{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}'`

```
def insertIntoDatabase(message):
    """Inserts the mqtt data into the database"""

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        print("Inserting data...)
        # MQTT message always a byte object
        # message.payload contains message sent in this format 
        b'{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}'
        # Covert to string ***WORKS***
        test_json = message.payload.decode('utf8')
        # Convert string to dict ***WORKS***
        json_dict = json.loads(test_json)
        print(json_dict)
        # How do I deconstruct the dict into an sql insert???? 
        # Inserts JSON into single column. Need one column per key
        cursor.callproc('InsertIntoMQTTTable', [str(message.topic), 
                        str(message.payload)[2:][:-1], int(message.qos)])
        connection.commit()
```

SQL Routine - Called via callproc

```
    create function insertintomqtttable(topic text, message text, 
    qos numeric) returns void
    
    language plpgsql
    as
    $$
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mqtt (createdAt, topic, message, qos)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, topic, message, qos);
        END;
    $$;

    alter function insertintomqtttable(text, text, numeric) owner to don;
```

postgres Table Structure -

```
    CREATE TABLE mqtt (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        topic TEXT NOT NULL,
        message TEXT,
        qos NUMERIC(1) NOT NULL
     );
```

Comment: If I get it right, the part that bothers you is how to log the data from python to the Postgres db ? You need to chose a package to connect and execute queries into your database (like `psycopg` ). Seems like the usual and safest way to do. The package will pretty much tell you what structure to use for input. About the similarity of the JSON between devices, why don't you use one unique table where you log all the device data (even different types) and just put an uuid column to know which device the log comes from ?

Comment: 1) I am not seeing how you get `topic, message, qos` from this `{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}`? 2) If you have a `dict` then used `named` parameters as shown here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to directly INSERT the data using `execute` from here [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver those are MQTT fields, that the op shouldn't be storing in the database, the only but of interest should be the byte array in `message.payload` which holds the JSON

Comment: @Adrian Klaver - Thank you. Based on your direction I found the correct path. I have inserted the working code above as an edit. Now the hard part... DB Architecture. Fun fun...